# Project tab stucked on loading screen How can I see my project folder on left?

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

When I open my project on android studio I can not see my project folder left, It stucked 'loading'. It doesnt a big problem but it is annoying, how can I put my project folder here again ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the dropdown menu in the top left where it says Android and then select Project. Then you'll see all your files and folders.